# What is the maximum upper limit on number of Columns in a SQL Server view?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I am creating a view which will be a join of a few tables that I have. And I need more than 14K columns in my view to write where clause. I am not sure about the maximum numbers of columns in a SQL Server view.

Let's say I have two entities, entity A and entity B. Now Entity A can have multiple value for B

Like

```
A.id, B.id,  Value
(A1  , B1 ,   5)
(A1  , B2   ,6)
(A1   ,B3   ,7)
(A2   ,B2   ,7)
(A2  , B1   ,8)
(A2  , B3  , NULL)
(A1  , B4  , NULL )
```

I want list of A's where B1 is 5 and B2 is 6.

BTW my B table has 14K records.

Comment: Removed the MySQL tag since this question is about SQL Server. Please, don't add tags that aren't related to the question

Comment: And do you really need more than 14K columns?, or do you mean rows?

Comment: If you need 14k columns, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: If you need 14K items for a where clause you should do it with a CTE instead.

Comment: Yes, It will be dynamic as I will be checking values of a row for 14K different entities and I will add them in columns.

Comment: Your update just made the question more confusing. You want a list of `A`s?, what are those?, a list of `id`s for the A entity where `B1` is 5 and `B2` is six?. Why would you need 14K columns for this?

Comment: @jbarker2160 I am not sure but what I understood from that example will also convert the result set with more than 14K columns for my case. I am not sure if I will be able to do so.

Comment: @user1863039, you haven't provided the structure of table B.  Having to create that many columns would be a waste of time and also impossible.

Comment: @Lamak: Yes. it is the existing design which i can not update. A1 , A2 is id of A. B1 , B2 is id of B, Value is lets say, cost of B. So each row denotes If I use B1 it will cost me 5 for A1 and it will cost 8 for B2. does that help in any way or is there any way we can discuss this personally ?
 I am new to this site and this is the first time I am asking any question.

Comment: @user1863039 But if that's your case, why do you need 14K columns?, I don't understand what's your desired output

Comment: In simple words I would say that Making Entity A takes multiple Entity  B Objects and It will also cost some money to use B in A. 

I want list of As where I have conditions on cost of Bs.
Like B1 should be less than 10$
and B2 should be less than 20$. 
Now give me list all the As for which I can get this specification

Comment: @Lamak What I want to do is to create a view in such way where I each row will present an A and colomu will represent B. Like 

ID of A , cost of B1 , cost of b2 , cost of b3, cost of b4.
(A1 , 5 , 6, 7, NULL) 
(A2 , 8 , 7 , null , null).

Now I can write simple where clause where costofB1 = 5 and cost of B2 = 6. which will return in first row.

So the number of Bs will be number of Column I need for my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

4,096 is the answer according to [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx).

Comment: That's the number of columns that you can use on a `SELECT`, not the maximum number of columns for a table. Anyway, your link also shows those values, 1,024 for a non wide table and 30,000 for a wide table

Comment: Ah, sorry, I read the question as the maximum columns for a table.

Comment: SO for a view this limit is 1024. Right ?

Comment: No, a view would be limited to 4,096 as it is a select. Perhaps you should post a new question showing the data and explain what you are trying to do and the desired output.

Comment: @SpectralGhost
Please see this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26748599/how-to-create-a-view-with-14000-columns-in-it