# How to create a view with 14000 Columns in it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have two tables

1. Shop
2. Item.

and a third table which shows availability of Item in a shop with cost of the item in that shop.

Shop_Item_Mapping.

Some sample data of Item would be `(1,  Candy`) where 1 is id and Candy is name of the Item.

```
(2 , Chocolate)
(3 , Chair)
(4 , Mobile)
(5 , Bulb)
```

Some sample data of Shop table would be

```
(1 , Address Of Shop)
(2 , Address Of Shop)
(3 , Address of the shop)
```

Now my mapping table shows me that which Item is available in which shop and at what cost.

```
Shop_Item_Mapping ( Shop_id , Item_Id , Cost of Item).
```

So my mapping tables have these entries

```
SID , IID , Cost
(1  , 1,   5)
(1  , 2   ,10)
(1   ,4   ,2300)
(2   ,3   ,50)
(2  , 5   ,10)
(3  , 1  , 4)
(3  , 2  , 5 )
(3  , 4  , 2500 )
(3  , 5  , 12 )
```

Now I have a query that I want all those shops which have both Mobile ( id = 4 ) and Chocolates(id = 2)  with mobile price < 3000 and chocolate price less than 7.

I am trying to make a view where I will have data like this
Shop_ID , I1 , I2 , I3 , I4 , I5 where I1 , I2 , I3 , I4 , I5 are the id of Items and value of these will be cost of the item in that shop.
So my view would be

```
(1 , 5 , 10 , NULL , 2300 , NULL ) 
(2 , NULL , NULL , 50 , NULL , 10)
(3 , 4 , 5 , NULL , 2500 , 12 ).
```

I am able to do so when my items are less. But IF I have more than 15000 Items in my repository, Can I create a view with these many columns ?

Comment: Your question is confusing. To me you seem to be using the word `Columns` where you should be using the word `Rows` - why would you need 14000 columns, you just need 6 columns with < 15000 rows (depending upon the data and the criteria). Can you please clarify the question. Also, this may all be clearer if you post the ACTUAL table definitions and the SQL you have tried.

Comment: Why do you want a view like that?  What are you actually trying to accomplish?  It seems to me you can just JOIN Shop, Item, and Shop_Item_Mapping and get the same data with lots of rows instead of lots of columns.  @Turophile I think they will have thousands of items, and thus their view will have thousands of columns (one for every item).

Comment: I'd do what Kevin suggests, and pivot the data on the client side, rather than in the view.

Comment: Plain and simple: **this cannot be done**. If you check the [Maximum Capacity Specifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) for SQL Server 2008, there's a **4096 column** limit on any `SELECT` statement ....

Comment: There has to come a point where you stop what you're working on and wonder whether there's a better way to do it. You should have already reached that point well *before* you start hitting the maximum capacity limitations in SQL Server. So my advice would be *stop* what you're doing, think more about the overall problem, and come up with a better overall design.

Answer (score 2):

Seriously? 14,000 columns in a view? You have a serious design issue here. However if you want to have a go, try this dynamic pivot query. It works with the limited data you have provided:

```
DECLARE @ColumnList VARCHAR (MAX)
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)


-- Create a list of distinct Item IDs which will become column headers
SELECT @ColumnList = COALESCE(@ColumnList + ', ','') + 'ItemID' + CAST(I.ItemID AS VARCHAR(12)) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ItemID FROM Item) I


SET @SQL = '
SELECT
  ShopID, ' + @ColumnList + '
FROM
(  
  SELECT
    s.ShopID,
    ItemID = ''ItemID'' + Cast(i.ItemID as varchar(12)),
    sim.ItemCost
  FROM
      dbo.Shop_Item_Mapping AS sim
      JOIN dbo.Shop AS s ON sim.ShopID = s.ShopID
      JOIN dbo.Item AS i ON SIM.ItemID = i.ItemID
)  T
PIVOT
(
    MIN(ItemCost)
    FOR T.ItemID IN (' + @ColumnList + ')
) AS PVT'


exec (@SQL)
```

Edited field names as per updated question.

Comment: I was using the pivot. But Pivot also have limit and I can not have more than 4096 columns. This is the reason I am facing some issues.

Comment: @user1863039 If you let me know why you need a view with so many columns maybe I/we can suggest alternative approaches to your problem.